# Can employers see how many employer messages I have said "No thanks" to?

Tags: discussion, jobs, privacy

If an employer looks at my resume, sends me a message and I respond to that message to say "Yes I'm interested" or "No thanks" or "I'm not looking for work right now" (the three default system responses), is it possible for other employers to see any statistics about how I have responded to previous employer messages that I have received or is this private between me and the employer who sent me the message? (I'm hoping the latter is the case.)

Answer (score 1):

Employers can only see your responses to them, not anyone else.

Comment: I'd refer you to Jeff's answer: Employers can *only see your responses to them*...